# With a node.js powered server on EC2, how can I decrease the TCP connection time?

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2

While profiling my application I've noticed that in the Firebug Net panel, the "Connecting" time—that is the time waiting for a TCP connection—is consistently around 70–100ms. See image below:

[image: notice "connecting"]

Of course in the grand scheme of things, 100ms is not long, but I have seen other services that respond with 0ms Connect time. So if other servers can, I should be able to as well.

Any thoughts on how I might even beging to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 1):

I would start with looking to see if iptables is doing anything that may get in the way. Also, if you were working with an ELB load balancer, (or any other load balancing), I'd remove it from the mix and see if you are still having the longer than expected connect time.

You could also separately install lighttpd or Apache and see what happens. If you get a lower connect time, than  that would point to your Node.js build. Although not definitively.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a simple test to check if this problem is related to your server:

1. Launch another instance in the same availability zone as your server.
2. Benchmark your server with Apache Benchmark from the second instance:

   `ab -c 1 -n 20000 http://<private_server_instance_ip>:<port>/<URL>`

   It is important to put private IP here, not private or public DNS to sweep aside domain name resolution effects.
3. Check the average time taken per request: If it will be around 1 ms - the problem described is not of your server.

Benchmarking with FireFox BTW may not be the best idea because the results might depend on a number of circumstances.